Program in docker container not found when using singularity
I created the following docker container (basically, I am just installing a program called coptr so that I can run it using the container):
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install git wget
RUN mkdir -p /opt/conda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /opt/conda/minic\
onda.sh \
  && bash /opt/conda/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda
RUN /opt/miniconda/bin/conda update -n base -c defaults conda
RUN git clone https://github.com/tyjo/coptr
RUN cd coptr/

ENV PATH=/opt/miniconda/bin/:/opt/conda/envs/coptr/bin:/coptr:$PATH

RUN conda init bash \
    && . ~/.bashrc \
    && conda env create -f /coptr/coptr.yml \
    && conda activate coptr \
    && pip install /coptr/.

RUN echo "source activate coptr" > ~/.bashrc

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "coptr"]

Then I tag and put in my dockerhub:
docker tag coptr:latest rbarrant/coptr:0.1
docker push rbarrant/coptr:0.1

And can run it without problems using docker:
docker run -it rbarrant/coptr:0.1 coptr

But then when I use singularity it can't find the command!
singularity exec docker://rbarrant/coptr:0.1 coptr


INFO:    Using cached SIF image
FATAL:   "coptr": executable file not found in $PATH

What am I missing?
